# This builds well.why doesn't this code execute?

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to make a web scraper using go. I built this code. It was built fine without any errors. But its binary won't execute.

Is this the problem with a large number of routines or those variables in the execute function?

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    //"regexp"
)

func excuter(count int) {

    adrr := string("http://torhit.com/torbite/?page=" + string(count))

    resp, _ := http.Get(adrr)
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    ioutil.WriteFile("scrap.txt"+string(count), bytes, 0777)

    resp.Body.Close()
}
func main() {
    //re := regexp.MustCompile("")
    count := 1
    maxcount := 200
    for ; count <= maxcount; count++ {
        go excuter(count)

    }
}

    package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    //"regexp"
)

func excuter(count int) {

    adrr := string("http://torhit.com/torbite/?page=" + string(count))

    resp, _ := http.Get(adrr)
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    ioutil.WriteFile("scrap.txt"+string(count), bytes, 0777)

    resp.Body.Close()
}
func main() {
    //re := regexp.MustCompile("")
    count := 1
    maxcount := 200
    for ; count <= maxcount; count++ {
        go excuter(count)

    }
}
```

Comment: Just because a program builds doesn't mean it works. Runtime errors are common place in real software applications and in your code you ignore every single error that is returned. Rather than doing `val, _ :=` everywhere, do `val, err :=` and then follow it with an `if err != nil` and print/log the errors. As it is, no one can offer you any further help because you have nothing to go off of.

Comment: ok @evanmcdonnal thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your error is come from this :

```
string(count)
```

It will compiled but the result is empty. If you want to convert int to string you will need strconv package.

```
strconv.Itoa(count)
```

Or

```
strconv.FormatInt(int64(count), 10)
```